# Dataset adding values by decimal but returning 0

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, decimal

I have a data-set with 2 columns. 
I'm adding the 2 values together, both are object(decimal) types.

```
private decimal CalculateCensusForChild(DataSet dsGADCensusDetails)
    {
        var total = 0.00M;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsGADCensusDetails.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            total += WebUtility.Cast(dr["Male"], 0.00M) + WebUtility.Cast(dr["Female"], 0.00M);
        }
        return total;
    }

public static decimal Cast(Object aValue, decimal aOnError)
    {
        decimal result;
        try
        {
            result = decimal.Parse(aValue.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            result = aOnError;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The total returns fine when the values are whole int numbers but I'm looking for them to be decimal values and thus return a decimal value which I will later turn into a string with no decimal places.

e.g 0.65 + 0.25 returns 0.

The total will always equal a whole number but it's required on the UI to show decimal values to reduce rounding, so bit of workaround that may seem unnecessary but that's the world we live in.

So I think I'm messing up on syntax to convert it to a decimal while it's adding but any other ideas are very welcomed.

Cheers folks.

Comment: What is `WebUtility.Cast`? If you're trying to sum *decimal* values, why it your `Total` variable an `int`? (I'd rename it to `total` btw, to follow normal conventions.)

Comment: You need to use `decimal` type for total. and post code for `WebUtility.Cast`. Presumably it rounds the value to nearest integer which you don't want it to.

Comment: Made the changes you guys mentioned and uploaded the cast method, appears to be working in a better state now but feel free to add more comments if you think I could do better :)